# How to do a complicated @PreAuthorize check for an ID that is contained in child property?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-el

According to this great post [Spring-Boot @PreAuthorize allow operation only for admin or if the authenticated user id is same as path parameter id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156564/spring-boot-preauthorize-allow-operation-only-for-admin-or-if-the-authenticated)

it is shown that you can match the URL id against the user id using:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN) or #authUser.id == #userId")
```

but what if I need to check if userId matches a child of authUser?

So suppose I have entity:

```
public class User {
 int id;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
 Set<Store> stores;
}
```

and I want to validate based on #userId == #authUser.ANY_ONE_OF_THE_STORES.id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the component, for example

```
@Component
public class AuthComponent {
    public boolean hasPermission(User user, Long id) {
        // do whatever checks you want here
        return someResult;
    }
}
```

And then you can access the component method in SPEL like this

```
@PreAuthorize("@authComponent.hasPermission(#authUser, #userId)")
```

Since SPEL supports bean reference via @ [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-bean-references)

Comment: Sorry #authUser turns out to be null, any ideas?

Comment: Probably the signature types of the methods of your component do not match with the types of parameters you are trying to pass. Could I see your method on which you use @PreAuthorize?

Comment: In the example, you provide they have @CurrentUser authUser in the method signature. Do you have it as well? Also, you actually can use builtin keywords for principal/authentication, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

Comment: thats the thing, even in the docs it makes no reference to authUser, so what is that? signature matches because the method is called but the param is null. Anyway I got it working but just grabbing the user from within the method, more code but oh well. will award answer

Comment: You can reference the parameters of your method below @PreAuthorize annotation in your SPEL. In the example, they have authUser in the method as a parameter, so they can use them